# What dose the expression "m |= Modifier.PUBLIC" mean and why do things in that way?

Tags: java, optimization, reflection, syntax

I am learning about reflection and I found some snippet that looks like this:

```
private static int modifierFromString(String s) {
    int m = 0x0;
    if ("public".equals(s))           m |= Modifier.PUBLIC;
    else if ("protected".equals(s))   m |= Modifier.PROTECTED;
    else if ("private".equals(s))     m |= Modifier.PRIVATE;
    else if ("static".equals(s))      m |= Modifier.STATIC;
    else if ("final".equals(s))       m |= Modifier.FINAL;
    else if ("transient".equals(s))   m |= Modifier.TRANSIENT;
    else if ("volatile".equals(s))    m |= Modifier.VOLATILE;
    return m;
}
```

I am very confused, what does the `m |= Modifier.PUBLIC` mean and can I use `m = Modifier.PUBLIC`?

Comment: It's a [bitwise or](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html), which is used to combine multiple values. But in this case, each result is in a separate `else`, so you can technically modify it as you suggested. I'm actually a bit surprised to see such code from an [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldModifiers.html).

Comment: `|=` is a Compound Assignment Operator, combining `=` (assignment) and `|` (bit-wise OR).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m |= Modifier.PUBLIC;` is equivalent to `m = m | Modifier.PUBLIC;`, which means you perform bit-wise OR on `m` and `Modifier.PUBLIC` and assign the result back to `m`.

Since your method executes just one such assignment to `m` and `m` is initialized to 0, you can replace it with simple assignment (`m = Modifier.PUBLIC;`) and get the same output.

Comment: Or just `return` and get rid of `m`. And these days, the `if` can become a `switch`.